# Splitview segue and unwinding

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I'm using a weird setup in my splitview Ipad app where i need some help with.

I have a TVC and a Normal View side by side in the split view. When i select something in my TVC both the screens segue to another TVC and Normal View. This part works fine. I'm using the push method with destination Master Split & Detail Split.

The problem is going back. I want to press 1 button and unwind both segues. I do this by this method: [https://github.com/bradley/iOSUnwindSegueProgramatically[1]](https://github.com/bradley/iOSUnwindSegueProgramatically%5b1%5d)

This has 1 problem tho. The button being clicked to activate my segues is located in the detail view. So the detail view segues back no problem. The Master view however does not segue i'm stuck on how to get that working the same way.

The other option i figured i could do is do a normal segue and than use a custom transition animation but that seems like more of a "hack". So i was wondering if i could segue my TVC back through the detail view.

I hope i'm being clear on how i'm setup and where i need to go.

Cheers,

Comment: @rmaddy Table view controller
Edit:
Now that i am reading this back it should state i have a table view and a normal view side by side. Behind it is a TVC(Table View Controller) and a VC (View Controller)

Comment: Good to clarify because TVC could have meant Tab View Controller.

Answer (score 2):

There is a note in Matt Neuburg's iOS7 book that in some situations you need to subclass UISplitViewController, and put the unwind method in the subclass. You might try that (but be sure to remove it from the detail controller, since only the first one in the chain is called.)